# Logic for IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

I have data in Excel like this:

```
   A
 1|id
 2|2
 3|4
 4|8
 5|12
 6|16
 7|20
 8|24
 9|28
10|32
11|36
12|40
```

I want to populate the value in another column depending upon the following criteria:

```
if cell A2>0 && cell A2<=8 
    return 1
else if cell A2>8 && cell A2<=16 
    return 2
else if cell A2>16 && cell A2<=24 
    return 3
else if cell A2>24 && cell A2<=32 
    return 4
else return 5
```

I was only able to do it for one `IF` condition:

```
=IF(AND(A2>0,A2<8),1)
```

How can I add logic for `else if`?

Comment: Why do you need VBA for this? Also are your elseif conditions same. They should be different... Result of a copy paste? :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Sorry, my bad. Actually that was a copy paste :D

Comment: Thought so. Already posted an answer

Comment: Thanks to @SiddharthRout.
Just for reference:
`=IF(AND(F2>0,F2<=8),1,IF(AND(F2>8,F2<=16),2,IF(AND(F2>16,F2<=24),3,IF(AND(F2>24,F2<=32),4,5))))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I said in my comments above, you don't need vba for this.

The `IF` has the following syntax

```
=If(Condition, Do If True, Do If False)
```

So in your case

```
Condition = AND(A2>0,A2<8)
Do If True = 1
Do If False = Nothing?
```

So `Do If False` is the place where you will set the next condition. For example

```
=If(Condition, Do If True, If(Condition, Do If True, Do If False))
```

And So on...

Something like this I am taking the 2nd condition (>8,<16) as an example. Change as applicable.

```
=IF(AND(A2>0,A2<8),1,IF(AND(A2>8,A2<16),2,Next condition goes here))
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the formula that you are using? Also mention what did you expect and what did you get

Comment: Is it giving unexpected results for 8,16 and 24 ;)?

Comment: `=IF(AND(F173>0,F173<=8),1,IF(AND(F173>8,F173<=16),2,IF(AND(F173>16,F173<=24),3,IF(AND(F173>24,F173<=32),4,IF(F175>32,5)))))` gives me false if value of a cell is higher than 40!

Comment: Because your formula is incorrect. Try this `=IF(AND(A2>0,A2<8),1,IF(AND(A2>8,A2<16),2,IF(AND(A2>16,A2<24),3,IF(AND(A2>24,A2<32),4,5))))`

Comment: `=IF(AND(F117>0,F117<=8),1,IF(AND(F117>8,F117<=16),2,IF(AND(F117>16,F117<=24),3,IF(AND(F117>24,f2‌​<=32),4,5))))` I used this, now I'm getting `#NAME?` where values are greater than 32.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64402/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-user1336087).

Answer (score 1):

Does not answer the question (for the likes of A2=8 etc) but produces the same results as seem to be required:

```
 =IF(OR(A2<=0,A2>32),5,INT(MOD((A2-MOD(A2-1,8))/8,8))+1)
```